# show tweets in a listview in twitter4j

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I have been playing around with twitter4j and Android and so far so good. However I am having problems figuring out how to display the tweets properly on a list View. Here is my code so far, based on the [code example given on the Twitter4j website](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/timeline/GetHomeTimeline.java):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
//ListView with the tweets
private ListView timelineListView; 

// Alert Dialog Manager
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

//Adapter
ArrayAdapter<twitter4j.Status> tweetAdapter ;  

//List
List<Status> rawStatuses;

//Other stuff
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_main);
//Login methods, checking that there is an Internet connection, etc... When a button is
//pressed, an Asynctask is called and it retrieves the tweets:


class updateTimeline extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void>{

    protected void onPreExecute(Void thing){

    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {           
        try {
            ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
            builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

            // Access Token
            String access_token = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
            // Access Token Secret
            String access_token_secret = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");

            AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token, access_token_secret);
            Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);
            User user = twitter.verifyCredentials();

            rawStatuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline();


            System.out.println("Showing @" + user.getScreenName() + "'s home timeline.");
            for (twitter4j.Status status : rawStatuses) {
                System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText()); 
                }

        } catch (TwitterException te) {
            te.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Failed to get timeline: " + te.getMessage());
            //System.exit(-1);
        }
        return null;
    }




    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        //pDialog.dismiss();

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Timeline updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();    
            tweetAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<twitter4j.Status>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, rawStatuses);
            timelineListView.setAdapter(tweetAdapter);
            }

        });
    }
```

It retrieves the last 20 tweets or so just fine. But my problems comes fromt he final part, where I bind the list rawStatuses to the adapter and the listView, because it basically prints ALL the information on screen:

[image: tweets]

Ok, not all that information is useful or ever needed, but it is there. And I don't know how to display in the listView only the Twitter handle and the tweet, for example (i.e. extract that information from the list rawStatuses properly). I thought about having a List with the most useful information (something like:
`List <User, Tweet, ID, Time>` ), but it seems to me cumbersome and a very poor solution.

My question is: How can or should manage all that information that a tweet contains (an many tweets) so I can display what I want and still have the rest? The closest answer I have found is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8883871/833937), but the link given doesn't work anymore.

I hope I have explained myself. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problem, and you're actually on the right path here.  What I did to resolve this was also create a list of Strings and storing that into an ArrayList, then putting that list into and ArrayAdapter rather that the raw statuses:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> stringTweetAdapter;
List<twitter4j.Status> statuses;
List<String> stringStatuses = new ArrayList<String>();

.....


User user = twitter.verifyCredentials();
statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline();
System.out.println("Showing @" + user.getScreenName() + "'s home timeline.");
for (twitter4j.Status status : statuses) {
 Log.d("Twitter","@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText());
 String myTweets = ("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText());
                stringStatuses.add(myTweets);
 }

......

protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
 // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
 progressDialog.dismiss();
 // updating UI from Background Thread
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Retrieving TimeLine Done..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    stringTweetAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ShowTimeline.this, R.layout.timeline_list_item, R.id.textTimelineItem, stringStatuses);
    twitterFeed.setAdapter(stringTweetAdapter);
    }
   });
  }
```

Comment: I should also point out that i am using my own layout rather than the default to map my ListView rather than using the default layout_list_item_1.